# ir-keytable and Imon as MCE remote for Kodi

Tags: remote

When I switched to Ubuntu to run my kodi media centre I manahged to get ir-keytable set up and work (under 18.10) and it worked well even through upgrades to 19 and then 20.04.  However, about 3 weeks ago it stopped working.  I had it set up to use the RC-6 protocol and MCE key maps, with a couple of changed keys.  So after a bit of fiddling I found that at each reboot the device switches to boot the "imon" protocal and standard "pad" key map.  If I "sudo ir-keytable -c -w ...." it loads the correct maps and works - until I reboot.  I have also tried to force the config file to only call the keytable I want (by making all imon ".toml" files have the same content) but this still doesnt work.  I have also tried "sudo ir-keytable -a ....", with no success.
I have noticed that the ".toml" files live in "/lib/udev/rc_keymaps" rather than the quoted "/etc/rc_keymaps" and have made sure they are all the same content (calling rc-6 and mce keymaps), but still it reverts during reboot.

Now I'm stuck... it used to work, but something was changed and now I cant get it to work - Help!

thanks
C

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find an solution, so thought it best to post for others.  Its built from this youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guMX3umfFG8

As he says the changes that happen when we use the "ir-keytable" command dont stick at reboot, so the solution is to use "systemd" to get the change to load everytime you restart. To do this, create a new file in:
/etc/systemd/system/
called "ir_remote.service"

Then in that file write:

---

[Unit]
Description= Remap IR Remote

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ir-keytable -c -w /etc/rc_keymaps/YOUR_KEY_MAP.toml

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

---

This should then run when you reboot.
Good luck!